# Как сделать метод const и неconst одновременно?

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++, методы, структуры

Пишу свою структуру данных в виде шаблона struct. В ней должен быть помимо прочего метод front() для обращения к определенному элементу.
Проблема в том, что этот метод нужен и для сравнения этого элемента с внешними (возврат значения из функции по константной ссылке) и для присвоения элементу значения (возврат из функции обычной ссылки). Я пробовал писать два метода, либо вложенную структуру которая съедает круглые скобочки и переопределяет оператор присваивания. Получалась какая-то лажа. Покажите какую-нибудь каноничную реализацию такого.

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, std::size_t MaxElements>
struct cb{
T buffer[MaxElements];
// Тут реализация метода front() который возвращает buffer[0]
};

int main(){cb<int,7>cc;cc.front()=0;if(cc.front()==0){};return 0;};
```

Comment: Покажите свой код. Потому что обычно как раз и пишется пара вариантов - если я правильно понял, что вы хотите...

Comment: @Harry дописал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написать две функции-члена. Одну для `const` обьектов, вторую для обычных обьектов.

```
T& front()
{
    return buffer[0];
}

const T& front() const
{
    return buffer[0];
}
```

P.S. Не забудьте написать нужные проверки в этих функциях.

Comment: Ок, я такой вариант не перебирал, не очень понятно почему в конце первой строчки нет const ведь в процессе поиска buffer[0] этот метод ничего не меняет.

Comment: @AndreyKomisarov тогда бы перегрузка не работала. Для Вашего кода в `main` хватило бы и одной функции без `const`, но если бы обьявили обьект `cc` как `const`, то не смогли бы вызвать для него метод `front` даже если бы не изменяли обьект.